# Symbol estimates using metric on the phase space

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, pseudo-differential-operators

Consider the symbols introduced by Beals and Fefferman in which the symbol estimates are of the form:
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
   \label{eq1}
   |\partial_x^\beta\partial_\xi^\alpha a(x,\xi)| \leq C_{\alpha \beta} M(x,\xi) \Phi(x,\xi)^{-|\alpha|} \varphi(x,\xi)^{-|\beta|}, \quad (x,\xi) \in \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n,
\end{equation}
where the positive functions $M,\Phi, \varphi$ satisfy certain conditions.

Now from the book- Metric on the Phase Space and Non-Selfadjoint Pseudodifferential Operators by N. Lerner (Chapter 2 Section 2.2), it is said that by considering the following Riemannian structure on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$
$$
  g_{x,\xi} = \frac{|dx|^2}{\varphi(x,\xi)^2} + \frac{|d\xi|^2}{\Phi(x,\xi)^2}: \; \text{ for }(t,\tau)\in \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n, g_{x,\xi}(t,\tau) = \frac{|t|^2}{\varphi(x,\xi)^2} + \frac{|\tau|^2}{\Phi(x,\xi)^2},
$$
one can write the symbol estimate in
(\ref{eq1}) for $|\alpha|+|\beta|=1,$ in terms of the metric as below:
\begin{equation}\label{eq2}\tag{2}
   |\nabla a(X)\cdot T|\leq C g_{X}(T)^{1/2},
\end{equation}
for $X=(x,\xi), T=(t,\tau).$

I tried to see the estimate (\ref{eq2}), in the following two ways:

For the sake of demonstration let's take $n=1.$

(I) Considering $\nabla$ w.r.t Euclidean metric:  I have
$$
   \begin{aligned}
   |\nabla a(X)\cdot T| &= |(\partial_xa,\partial_\xi a) \cdot (t,\tau)|\\
            &= |t\partial_xa +\tau \partial_\xi a|\\
            &\leq C \Big( |t| \frac{M}{\varphi} + |\tau| \frac{M}{\Phi}\Big)\\
            &=  CM \Big\{\frac{|t|}{\varphi} +  \frac{|\tau|}{\Phi}\Big\}\\
            &\leq CM(g_X(T)^{1/2} + g_X(T)^{1/2})\\
            &= 2CMg_X(T)^{1/2}
   \end{aligned}
$$

(II) Considering $\nabla$ w.r.t metric $g$, in which case
$$
     \nabla a = (\varphi^2\partial_x a,\Phi^2\partial_\xi a).
 $$
Then
$$
   \begin{aligned}
   |\nabla a(X)\cdot T| &= |(\varphi^2\partial_x a,\Phi^2\partial_\xi a) \cdot (t,\tau)|\\
            &= |t\varphi^2\partial_xa +\tau \Phi^2\partial_\xi a|\\
            &\leq C \Big( \varphi^2|t| \frac{M}{\varphi} + \Phi^2 |\tau| \frac{M}{\Phi}\Big)\\
            &=  CM \{\varphi|t| +  \Phi|\tau|\}, 
   \end{aligned}
$$
after this I am unable to go further to establish (\ref{eq2}).

**My questions**:

1. When the author (N .Lerner) says to consider the metric $g$ what does he mean? Should we consider gradient $\nabla$ w.r.t Euclidean metric or w.r.t $g$?
2. If $\nabla$ has to be considered w.r.t $g$, how do I proceed further in my calculations?
3. If $\nabla$ has to be considered w.r.t Euclidean metric, then what exactly is the role of $g$?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are given a metric on the phase space, i.e. at each point $(x,\xi)$ in $\mathbb R^{2n}$ a positive definite quadratic form $g_{x,\xi}$ on $\mathbb R^{2n}$. You will use that metric (and the affine connection on $\mathbb R^{2n}$) to express the conditions on the symbols.

In the first place, the metric $g$ must be slowly varying, temperate and should satisfy the uncertainty principle according to the references to Lerner's book. Next, you introduce a weight function $m$ defined on the phase space and valued in $(0,+\infty)$, with slow variation and temperate requirements as in the same reference.

Then you define the space of symbols $S(m,g)$ as the set of smooth functions $a$ on the phase space such that
$$\forall k\in \mathbb N, \exists C_k,\forall X\in \mathbb R^{2n},\forall T\in \mathbb R^{2n}, \quad
\vert a^{(k)}(X) T^k\vert\le C_k m(X)g_X(T)^{k/2}.
\tag 1$$
Since the tensor products $T_1\otimes\dots\otimes T_k$ are sums of powers
$S^{\otimes k}$ where $S$ is a linear combination of the vectors $T_j$, it turns out that $(1)$ is equivalent to
\begin{multline}\forall k\in \mathbb N, \exists C_k,\forall X\in \mathbb R^{2n},\forall \{T_j\}_{1\le j\le k}\in \mathbb R^{2n}, \quad
\\
\vert a^{(k)}(X) (T_1,\dots, T_k)\vert\le C_k m(X)\prod_{j=1}^{j=k}g_X(T_j)^{1/2}.
\tag{2}\end{multline}
When you have chosen some symplectic coordinates such that, for a given point $(x,\xi)$ in the phase space, you have
$$
g_{x,\xi}(t_1,\dots,t_n, \tau_1,\dots, \tau_n)=\frac{\vert t_1\vert^2}{r_1^2}
+\dots+\frac{\vert t_n\vert^2}{r_n^2}
+
\frac{\vert \tau_1\vert^2}{\rho_1^2}
+\dots+\frac{\vert \tau_n\vert^2}{\rho_n^2},
$$
the estimates $(1), (2)$ are equivalent to
$$
\bigl\vert\bigl(\partial_{t_1}^{b_1}\dots\partial_{t_n}^{b_n}
\partial_{\tau_1}^{\beta_1}\dots\partial_{\tau_n}^{\beta_n} a\bigr)(t,\tau)\bigr\vert
\le C_{b_1,\dots, b_n,\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n}
m(t,\tau)\Bigl(\prod_{j=1}^{j=n} r_j^{-b_j}\Bigr)\Bigl(\prod_{j=1}^{j=n} \rho_j^{-\beta_j}\Bigr).
$$
Note that in this framework, you have
$$
g^\sigma_{x,\xi}=
{\vert t_1\vert^2}{\rho_1^2}
+\dots+{\vert t_n\vert^2}{\rho_n^2}
+
{\vert \tau_1\vert^2}{r_1^2}
+\dots+{\vert \tau_n\vert^2}{r_n^2},
$$
so that the "uncertainty principle" condition $g_{x,\xi}\le g^\sigma_{x,\xi}$ reads
$$
\min_{1\le j\le n}\rho_j r_j\ge 1.
$$